# Show a confirmation message based on input value after invoking action method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, confirm

I need to call a confirmation message from my save method in backing bean if the value entered in a text box is not as expected.

Confirmation dialog looks like this

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" header="Confirmation" global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" widgetVar="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" action="#{MBean.Save()}" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value=No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" >  icon="ui-icon-close" />  
</p:confirmDialog>`
```

In the save method

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
context.execute("Confirmation.show()");
```

But I am not able to call the confirmation message in my JSF page. Does anybody knows why?

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using? If it is PF >= 4.x then you will need context.execute("PF('Confirmation').show();")

Comment: Which kind of message did you want to display ?

Comment: What means _not as expected_? Can you be a little bit more specific please?

Answer (score 3):

Confirm dialog is for **upfront** asking for confirmation if a business method in your backing bean should be called at all.

If you want to show a dialog that functions as confirmation after your business method in the backingbean is called or more specifically from it, use a normal dialog.